# Actionscript 3 not hitTest

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a code for a "not" hitTest, like `if(player.notHitTestObject(object))` similarly as we do for collision detection like so,

```
if(player.hitTestObject(object)) {

}
else {

}
```

I know else is the same, but is there a different way?

Comment: `if(!player.hitTestObject(object)){`. Notice the `!`. This is the "not" operator. You might also want to play with `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 2):

The '!' operator or NOT operator is what you want to use.

hitTestObject returns a boolean (true/false), so you can do this :

```
if (!player.hitTestObject(object))
{
    // code to run if hit test is not true
}
```